# Apex web services

Tags: wsdl

I have generated  an apex class from wsdl but I have done everything to connect to the application without any success. The @IsTest is not working and neither did every other things that I tried.
I tried to connect with this:

```
ticketinformationwebservicerftojtra.TicketInformationRFtoJtracPort s1 = new ticketinformationwebservicerftojtra.TicketInformationRFtoJtracPort();
String result;
result = s1. ticketInformationRFtoJtrac();
System.Debug(result);
```

Comment: Note, you won't be able to connect with @IsTest.  IsTest is specifically for when you write a unit test for your class.  Unit tests in Salesforce don't allow callouts either.  Now, are you seeing any exceptions thrown?  Have you added your services end point to Setup->Security->Remote Site Settings?

Comment: How can I connect then? Please, advice.

Comment: @Bunmi,
The client said that the application is opened and that I do not need to supply any credential to login in. Do you think that I need to perform any authentication?
What I am thinking is that I have not actually taken all the steps that I need to take. I have generated an Apex class and I have added the site under remote settings. The next thing I am trying to do is to call the method but I guess that maybe, I need to do something else. Please, advice. Tx guys

Comment: @James
Yes, I have added it in Remore Site Settings.

Comment: I recommend you visit https://developer.salesforce.com/docs and look at the links to the Apex Code Developer's Guide along with the Soap Developer's Guide and the REST Developer's guide for Web Services to learn more about what you need to do. In fact, you may want to take a peek at the Apex Workbook which has some starter instructions.

Comment: @crmprgdev, I have and that is why I am able to take it this far. I just need a little bit of direction. Thanks

Comment: how exactly is it not working ?

Comment: Voting to close as it is not clear what you are asking. If you are referring to test methods, check out the documentation on HTTPCalloutMock or WebserviceMock

Comment: @Eric, what I want is for the web service to work. I have generated an Apex class from the wsdl that I was given. The process is meant to create a call. Now, I am trying to call the method but its not working.
Initially, I was trying to test connection between RF (Salesforce) and the application but that too was not working. I tried to post the code but the site did not allowed to post it. That would have probably give you guys a better understanding of what  I am trying to achieve and where the problem might be coming from.

Answer (score 1):

You commented that you have added the required URL for the web service to the remote site settings. In that case, the answer to your question will be in the debug log.

Look for the CALLOUT_REQUEST and CALLOUT_RESPONSE elements. These will show the outbound payload JSON formatted and the SOAP request. It will also show the SOAP response.

Here is an example from another web service:

[image: CALLOUT_REQUEST and CALLOUT_RESPONSE]

If, for example, you have an authentication problem, you should be able to see the fault details in the response.

You can take the generated callout request soap message into a tool like SOAP UI and experiment until the correct response comes back before replicating the details in Apex.